# C++: What does thread t { F() } do?

Tags: c++

I am reading chapter 15 (concurrency) in Bjarne Stroustrup's "A Tour of C++". I don't understand his introductory example in section 15.2 (he makes a reference to section 6.3.2, which didn't seem to answer my question). The following actually compilable code originates from my endeavor to understand it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

struct F {
    void operator()();
};

void F::operator()()
{
    cout << "Hello" << endl;
}

void f()
{
    cout << "Hello" << endl;
}

int main()
{
    thread t1 { F() };
    thread t2 { f };
    thread t3(f);
    //thread t4(F()); (does not work)
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    t3.join();
}
```

I have two questions about it:

1. What does `thread t1 { F() };` do? I can't write the same with f in place of F (I didn't expect this would work). Also I had the theory that maybe F() is some sort of function pointer to F::operator() with a `nullptr` or something passed to it, but also this doesn't work:

```
void (a*)() = F();
```

So what does F() do in this context?

2. Why can I create this thread with a curly braced initializer and not with round brackets?

Comment: F() is call to constructor, so this creates a new object F.

Comment: `thread t4(F());` declares a function t4 that returns an object of the type thread and takes the argument of the type of a function that returns F.

Comment: Thank you! I actually feel stupid now for not having recognized that F() is a constructor. :)

Comment: BTW in the book there is a comment: "F()() executes in a separate thread..." So it's the call operator of the F instance created with F(), it all makes sense now...

Comment: It's not _really_ a "call to constructor"; there is no such syntax in C++ for that, even though it looks like one. You're "declaring" a temporary variable (sort of). But that's being picky.

Comment: Despite of all that I think it's a rather useless example, also because two different threads are doing exactly the same, so you can't tell from output from which thread it came.

Comment: @U. Windl Plus, the console output will most likely end up mangled. But that was not really the point. I was under the impression that this F() had something to do with F's calling operator. In hindsight that was stupid, since F is the struct's name and not the name of an instance, so the whole thing had actually nothing to do with threads.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the reference for [std::thread](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread), you are calling the following constructor for `t1`, `t2`, and `t3`:

```
template <class Function, class... Args>
explicit thread( Function&& f, Args&&... args);
```

where

> `f`   -   Callable object to execute in the new thread

---

`t1` is constructed from a direct-initialized object of type `F`. Since `F` has an `operator()`, it is a callable object, and so the declaration works.

Of course, `f` is a function, so it's definitely a callable thing, and so the declaration of `t2` works as well. `t3` is similar to `t2` with the only difference being that `t3` is direct-initialized, whereas `t2` is brace-initialized.

`t4` doesn't work because it's not actually declaring a thread at all. This is an example of a vexing parse. `t4` is actually  a function declaration, where the function returns a `thread`, and itself accepts a function that takes no arguments, and returns an `F`.